# Unhandled forced unwind causes abort

Tags: c++, exception, pthreads, terminate, abort

So my understanding of both `pthread_exit` and `pthread_cancel` is that they both cause an exception-like thing called a "forced unwind" to be thrown out of the relevant stack frame in the target thread.  This can be caught in order to do thread-specific clean-up, but must be re-thrown or else we get an implicit `abort()` at the end of the catch block that didn't re-throw.

In the case of `pthread_cancel`, that happens either immediately on receipt of the associated signal, or the next entry into a cancellation point, or when the signal is next unblocked, depending on the thread's cancellation state and type.

In the case of `pthread_exit`, the calling thread immediately undergoes a forced unwind.

Fine.  This "exception" is a normal part of the process of killing a thread.  So why, even when I re-throw it, is it causing `std::terminate()` to be called, aborting my whole application?

Note that I'm catching and re-throwing the exception a couple times.

Note also that I'm calling `pthread_exit` out of my `SIGTERM` signal handler.  This works fine in my toy test code, compiled with g++ 4.3.2, which has a thread run `signal(SIGTERM, handler_that_calls_pthread_exit)` and then sit in a tight `while` loop until it gets the `TERM` signal.  But it doesn't work in the real application.

Relevant stack frames:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000003425c30265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003425c31d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000012b7740 in sv_bsd_terminate () at exception_handlers.cpp:38
#3  0x00002aef65983aa6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=0x518)
    at /view/ken_gcc_4.3/vobs/Compiler/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:43
#4  0x00002aef65983ad3 in std::terminate ()
    at /view/ken_gcc_4.3/vobs/Compiler/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:53
#5  0x00002aef65983a5a in __cxxabiv1::__gxx_personality_v0 (
    version=<value optimized out>, actions=<value optimized out>, 
    exception_class=<value optimized out>, ue_header=0x645bcd80, 
    context=0x645bb940)
    at /view/ken_gcc_4.3/vobs/Compiler/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_personality.cc:657
#6  0x00002aef6524d68c in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind_Phase2 (exc=0x645bcd80, 
    context=0x645bb940)
    at /view/ken_gcc_4.3/vobs/Compiler/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/unwind.inc:180
#7  0x00002aef6524d723 in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (exc=0x645bcd80, 
    stop=<value optimized out>, stop_argument=0x645bc1a0)
    at /view/ken_gcc_4.3/vobs/Compiler/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/unwind.inc:212
#8  0x000000342640cf80 in __pthread_unwind () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x00000034264077a5 in pthread_exit () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x0000000000f0d959 in threadHandleTerm (sig=<value optimized out>)
    at osiThreadLauncherLinux.cpp:46
#11 <signal handler called>
```

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 7):

> Note also that I'm calling
>   pthread_exit out of my SIGTERM signal
>   handler.

This is your problem. To quote from the POSIX specs (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html):

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling abort(), raise(),  kill(), pthread_kill(), or sigqueue(),  **the behavior is undefined** if the signal handler refers to any object with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or **if the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than one of the functions listed in Signal Concepts.**

The list of permitted functions is given at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_03, and does not include `pthread_exit()`. Therefore your program is exhibiting undefined behaviour.

I can think of three choices:

1. Set a flag in the signal handler which is checked by the thread periodically, rather than trying to exit directly from the signal handler.
2. Use `sigwait()` to explicitly wait for the signal on an independent thread. This thread can then explicitly call `pthread_cancel()` on the thread you wish to exit.
3. Mask the signal, and call `sigpending()` periodically on the thread that is to be exited, and exit if the signal is pending.