# concurrency::task destructor causes call to abort in valid use-case

Tags: c++, concurrency-runtime

Could you please tell me if the approach I use to handle the use-case is invalid and if so, what is the right way to handle:

```
task<int> do_work(int param)
{
    // runs some work on a separate thread, returns task with result or throws exception on failure
}

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        auto result_1 = do_work(10000);
        auto result_2 = do_work(20000);

        // do some extra work

        process(result_1.get(), result_2.get());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // logs the failure details
    }
}
```

So the code tries to execute two jobs in parallel and then process the results. If one of the jobs throws an exception, then call `task::get` will re-throw the exception. The issue happens if both tasks throw an exception. In this case the first call to `task::get` will cause stack unwind, so the destructor of the second `task` will be called and will in turn cause one more exception to be re-thrown during stack unwind which causes 'abort' to be called.

This approach seemed completely valid to me until I faced with the issue.

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766768/unhandled-forced-unwind-causes-abort?rq=1

Comment: Why does the (second) task throw from its destructor?

Comment: @StackedCrooked... This is actually the main question. Either I get it wrong or `task` destructor really re-throws the exception that was caught in the `do_work` function.

Comment: @Cyber... I do not see how it is related. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 3):

In simple words you have an un-handled (unobserved) exception as the exception thrown in one of your tasks does not get [caught by the task, one of its continuations, or the main app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx), because the exception re-thrown from task::get for the first task unwinds the stack before the call to task::get happens for the second task.

A more simplified code shows that `std::terminate` is called because the exception thrown in the task does not get handled. Uncommenting the `result.get()` will prevent the call to `std::terminate`, as `task::get` will re-throw the exception.

```
#include <pplx/pplx.h>
#include <pplx/pplxtasks.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        auto result = pplx::create_task([] ()-> int
        {
            throw std::exception("task failed");
        });

        // actually need wait here till the exception is thrown, e.g.
        // result.wait(), but this will re-throw the exception making this a valid use-case

        std::cout << &result << std::endl; // use it
        //std::cout << result.get() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

have a look at the suggestion in `pplx::details::_ExceptionHandler::~_ExceptionHolder()`

```
//pplxwin.h
#define _REPORT_PPLTASK_UNOBSERVED_EXCEPTION() do { \
    __debugbreak(); \
    std::terminate(); \
} while(false)


//pplxtasks.h
pplx::details::_ExceptionHandler::~_ExceptionHolder()
{
    if (_M_exceptionObserved == 0)
    {
        // If you are trapped here, it means an exception thrown in task chain didn't get handled.
        // Please add task-based continuation to handle all exceptions coming from tasks.
        // this->_M_stackTrace keeps the creation callstack of the task generates this exception.
        _REPORT_PPLTASK_UNOBSERVED_EXCEPTION();
    }
}
```

In the original code the first call to `task::get` raises the exception thrown in that task, which obviously prevents the second call to `task::get` so the exception of the second task does not get handled (remains "unobserved").

> the destructor of the second task will be called and will in turn cause one more exception to be re-thrown during stack unwind which causes 'abort' to be called.

The destructor of the second task does not re-throw the exception it just calls std::terminate() (which calls std::abort())

see. [Exception Handling in the Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx)

Comment: I see, thank you. So destructor does not re-throw (which is good), it just calls `std::terminate` (which is actually bad and does not change my question). The question is whether or not it is right to use the approach that I used. I seemed to me that the approach is absolutely valid: user fires several parallel tasks, then later gets their results and processes them. Now I see that it simply will not work if at least two tasks fail...